# iOS UIView Draw(CGRect rect) never called when I set VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using an iOS UIView for Custom control in Xamarin.IOS. I have used this control in Xamarin.Forms Xaml.

If I set my Grid Horizontal and VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand", My Draw() in UIView never gets called. It works fine if i set the value to 'FillAndExpand'.

My requirement is to place my custom control in center of my screen.
Is there any way to handle this? or is there other way I could display my UIView in Center of my screen.

```
<ScrollView>
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <localControls:CustomUIView />  
</Grid></ScrollView>
```

I need this  Draw(CGRect rect) method to get the Width and Height of the available size in Screen. Hence my Draw is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AbsoluteLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout/) to let the view to the center of screen.

> Views within an AbsoluteLayout are positioned using four values:
>
> - X – the x (horizontal) position of the view's anchor
> - Y – the y (vertical) position of the view's anchor
> - Width – the width of the view
> - Height – the height of the view
>
> Each of those values can be set as a proportional value or an absolute value.
>
> Values are specified as a combination of bounds and a flag. LayoutBounds is a Rectangle consisting of four values: x, y, width, height.

Code in Xaml like this:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <local:MyCustomView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,300,200" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

`AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,300,200" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"` means the anchor is the center of the screen. And the view's Width and Height is 300 and 200.

It works like this:

[image]

*BTW, I tried your code, but it works fine on my side with Visual Studio `15.3.5` and Xamarin.iOS `11.0.0.0`, updating yours may solve the `CenterAndExpand` issue.*